# Where in AOSP is the code to parse AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, parsing, android-manifest, android-source

I am attempting to understand how and when the AndroidManifest.xml for an application is parsed, but am unable to locate this is in the AOSP source. I searched [AndroidXRef](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/) as well, but I'm not seeing any hits (likely because this parsing is done as binary XML and so the tags -- such as `android:name` -- are not strings.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parsing of the package is performed in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java`. You need `parsePackage` method.

HTH!